# Undefined offset: 3 in custom function

Tags: php, functions

I am using this code as part of a function:

```
function photo_shortcode($atts){
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'no' => 1,
   ), $atts));

   $no     = is_numeric($no) ? (int) $no : 1;
   $images = get_field('fl_gallery');
   $image  = $images[$no];
}
```

`fl_gallery` is an ACF gallery field. However, sometimes I am getting PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1,2,3 etc.. on line `$image  = $images[$no];`

Why would this be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What is `$no`? And what does the value of `$images` look like?

Comment: Hi I have updated the code, $no is an integer which corresponds to which object to pick from the array $images

Comment: I suppose the error might be happening if you call the shortcode with [photo no="3"] but there are only 2 images in the fl_gallery ?

Comment: You shouldn't use `extract`, I also see your shortcode doesn't return anything, and you never check if `get_field` worked or not, you're just assuming it worked. What if there is n gallery? Or yoour shortcode runs before a post is set as the current post? Or on a 404 page? Clearly it didn't work and the code just carried on anyway, resulting in the PHP notices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assumed `get_field` would always return images, **but what if there are no images to return?**

```php
   $images = get_field('fl_gallery');
   $image  = $images[$no];
```

The code never checks `$images` to see if it's empty, or an error value.

On top of that, what if it returned images, but it returned 3 images, and `$no` is 4? You can't access something that doesn't exist without warnings, **you have to check first.** This is why you're getting PHP warnings.

For example:

```php
if ( empty( $images ) ) {
    // no images!
}

if ( empty( $images[$no] ) ) {
    // that image doesn't exist
}
```

However, you're using `get_field` which is an ACF API, not a WordPress API. You will need to consult the ACF documentation on what that function does when it encounters problems, and how to handle the error. It may not return an array at all but final HTML.

You'll also want to add more validation. For example `[photo_shortcode no=9000]` or `[photo_shortcodo no="-1"]` or `[photo_shortcode no="0.5"]` are all numeric and would generate those PHP warnings

*Sidenote: `extract` reduces security, makes code unreadable by machines and tools, and can overwrite variables unexpectedly enabling security holes and bugs. **Never use it.***